# ¿Como Crear un ASPxFileManager a código?

Tags: c#, devexpress, visual-studio-2013

Tengo un `ASPxFileManager` para explorar el contenido de una carpeta en un servidor. El problema es que para cada usuario es una carpeta diferente en el servidor. He leído en Internet que la propiedad `RootFolder` no se puede cambiar en tiempo de ejecución. Por lo que me hace falta saber cómo crear el control a mano y en ese caso personalizar el `RootFolder` para cada usuario. Cualquier ayuda me sería de gran importancia.

en el asp:

```
<dx:ASPxFileManager ID="fileEnviar" runat="server" Theme="iOS" Width="100%" EnableCallBacks="True" EnableCallbackAnimation="True">
    <Settings RootFolder="~\" ThumbnailFolder="~\Thumbs\"/>
    <SettingsFileList View="Details">
    </SettingsFileList>
</dx:ASPxFileManager>
```

y en el .cs:

```
int userId = services.GetUserId(user);
string codClient = services.GetClienteUserCod(userId);
using (new Impersonation("enlinea", "UserRemBan", "Bicsa!261a"))
{
    bool exist = System.IO.Directory.Exists("//enlinea/shared/FicherosBR/" + codClient + "/enviar");
    fileEnviar.Settings.RootFolder = "/FicherosBR/" + codClient;
    fileEnviar.Settings.ThumbnailFolder = "/FicherosBR/" + codClient + "/Thumb/";
    fileEnviar.Settings.InitialFolder = "/" + codClient + "/recibir";
}
```

Pero he leído que no puedo cambiar el `RootFolder` en tiempo de ejecución. Cuando compilo me dice que parte de la ruta no se encuentra. Pensé crearlo a mano, pero no tengo la menor idea de cómo hacerlo.

Comment: Hola Branly! ¿puedes mostrarnos como haces actualmente para crear el control? saludos!

Comment: Mira actualmente lo hago de la manera normal, es decir lo agrague como control web a mi pagina, pero lo q quiero hacer es crearlo yo mismo a codigo, es decir crearlo con todas las propiedades que necesite y depues agragarselo a mi pagina...como lo hago actualmente es asi:

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes que asignar el RootFolder de forma dinamica en runtime no necesitas crear todos el control sino solo asignar la propiedad

[ASPxFileManager - How to change RootFolder at runtime](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q405406)

[ASPxFileManager - How to set the RootFolder and InitialFolder on callback](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q368224)

como observaras teniendo el control definido en el webform puedes asignar la carpeta del root desde codigo

```
ASPxFileManager1.Settings.RootFolder ="~/"
```

pero accedes al control que tienes en el webform

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, pero la propiedad RootFolder segun he leido no se puede cambiar en el runtime, he tratado de hacerlo pero falla.

Comment: pero revisaste los links que puse del foro oficial del componente? porque alli dicen lo contrario. Mas alla de lo que hayas leido que mensaje de error recibes cuando asignas la propiedad? edita la respuesta y menciona el fallo que obtienes, porque la solucion no pasa por crear el control dinamcamente sino por asignar esa propiedad desde codigo

Comment: OK, te comprendo. Si revice los links del foro oficial del componente, de hecho ya lo habia hecho antes de formular la pregunta. La realidad es existen varias vias para definir el RootFolder del componente, pero simpre extaticamente, lei ademas que es una de las cosas que se le sugirieron a devExprees que revice.

Comment: Bueno amigo creo que lo resolvi, pero poco optimo... Le defini el RootFolder = ¨\\enlinea\shared\FicherosBR¨ y en el codigo le especifique que la propiedad InitialFolder = "/" + codClient +"/enviar".... y en el control le desabilite la opcion del arbol de ficheros, de esta forma el usuario solo vera su carpeta sin posibilidad de navegar por los ficheros..... que es lo que queria.

Comment: que bien, entonces desde codigo si puedes asignar la propiedad InitialFolder y al no poder navegar es verdad se conseguiria el mismo efecto

Comment: Exacto, la unica propiedad qno se puede asignar en el runtime es RootFolder, la explicacion no la tengo bien clara pero la practica de muestra q es imposible redefinirla... sabes que me documentare mas acerca de esta laguna de devexprees y que tiene pensado el equipo de desarrollo para el futuro, muchas gracias por tu colaboracion...Sakudos